Can I use the white wire on a cooktop for the additional phase of the power supply?
I have a cooktop with 3 wires and my power supply for 220v-240v 60amps has 4 wires. I can only get half the power connected if I leave the red disconnected. Can I just connect the red wire to the white wire on the cooktop to achieve full power?
So to recap it's a single phase 220v-240v 60amp appliance being hard wired to 3 phase Canadian power supply. Can I use the white wire on the appliance to get the extra 120v from the red wire?

That isn't a 3 phase supply. It is a 3 wire split phase.

Where did you get this cooktop? Do you have user/installation instructions for it?

Your title suggests that you think the cooktop requires 60 A at 220 V. Is this what the instructions state? Or is the circuit currently served with a 60 A breaker and the cooktop actually requires less than that? What is the siz of this cooktop and how many heating units does it have? What is the mfgr and model?

Yeah, how many kW is this cooktop rated for, according to its nameplate?

I am also worried about the 60 amps.  Make sure the cooktop requires 60 amps(a very big cooktop), and not a 30 or 40 amp cooktop on a 60 amp circuit.  Bad things will happen if stuff goes boom if on a bigger circuit.

Pictures of the wiring for both devices, the labeling of the cooktop, the circuit breaker supplying the circuit, and the exact brand/model number of the cooktop. Pleaase [edit] to add them to the question.

Neutral is always (except in conduit can be gray) white. White is not always neutral. The question isn't about "connecting neutral to hot" it is about "connecting white, which is usually neutral but may not be here, to hot"

That is not a 3-phase power supply, I can tell from your wire colors which are standardized in Canada. You have a split-phase supply 120/240V.
Follow the instructions and labeling that were issued with the range, as code requires you do.  They will explain what to do with the white wire.  A "seat of the pants" approach where you just match up the colors you see is not appropriate.
Most likely, it goes to the red wire and you cap off the supply hot, but that would just be more "seat of the pants" guessing, wouldn't it?
Make sure you also follow the instructions and labeling regarding circuit capacity.  To determine whether the load will fit in your electric service, follow the standard CEC load calculations.

yes you can.

Can I use the neutral on the appliance to get the extra 120v from the red wire?

If it's 220V and has only 2 power wires, the white on the appliance is not a neutral.

Note: Using 240V here as that is the usual value for US/Canada for the last few decades. However, the same applies if it is 220V with a 110V hot-neutral (as things were decades ago) or 208V which goes with 120V hot-neutral in certain distribution schemes that are common for apartment buildings but not common for single-family homes.
Wire Colors
US/Canada wiring in cables is generally:

2-wire cable (plus ground, which will be ignored for the rest of this answer): black and white
3-wire cable: black, red and white

If a 2-wire cable is used for 240V without neutral then white can be marked with another color and used as a hot wire instead of neutral. That is commonly done for circuits that never need neutral, such as EVSE ("car charging") and water heaters.
Similarly, an appliance can have a white wire that is hot rather than neutral. That isn't ideal, because it gets confusing, but if UL, ETL or a similar organization approved it then that's perfectly fine.
If you connect a 3-wire black/red/white (with white as neutral) with a 2-wire black/white (with white as hot) then you:

Connect black to black
Connected red to white
Leave the 3-wire white unused (capped with a wire nut)

What about 60A???
This is the part I'm worried about. 60A is a lot of power. Entire homes used to run on 60A, and many still can if they have gas heat, hot water and cooking appliances. 60A just for a cooktop is not as unusual as it used to be. But it may be more than your system can supply. In order to provide any amount of power, you need to:

Have an appropriately sized breaker. That's the easy part - a 60A non-GFCI (but things are changing to require GFCI for more circuits, so check your local code) costs less than $20 for some panels, though a lot more for others.
Have appropriately sized wire/cable. That is often a big problem. A 30A circuit (quite common for a cooktop or oven) uses 10 AWG cable. A 40A circuit uses 8 AWG cable. A 60A circuit may require as large as 4 AWG cable. But even more than the cost of the cable itself is the labor to install it. If your kitchen is right above your basement with the breaker panel (like mine) it is easy. If it is on the other side of the house with finished walls in between then it can be quite an ordeal to run a new cable.
Have enough service and panel capacity. This is the truly unexpected part for many people. If you started with 100A service 50 years ago and have gradually added more appliances, air conditioning and other things then it could be that replacing a 30A cooktop with a 60A cooktop will be the straw that breaks the camel's back - requiring a heavy-up to 200A and a new panel, etc. You need to do a NEC Load Calculation to figure out if you have the capacity before you start installation.


I am assuming this is a new cooktop.  If so would they place/use a white wire on the cooktop to be used as a second hot?  Instead of confusing people.

Waiting on pictures from the OP. Sometimes people think a two-pole 30 is a 60, which is why pictures are better than words, many times. A two pole 30 is a lot more likely if it was a cooktop (not a range with oven) before. But until pictures hard to be sure.
